# Как добавить и передать значение в функцию кода? Python

Tags: python, классы

```py
import random

class lightSensor():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def getValueL(self,):
        pass
```

У меня есть код сенсора света

```py
from LightSensor import lightSensor
lightS = lightSensor()
while True:
    statusL = lightS.getValueL()
    print(f"the lights are {statusL}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

и код сервера который каждую секунду проверяет сенсор света, **что нужно сделать что бы поместить в `getValue` рандомный off,on и что бы в сервера писался это значение**?

> ***ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО НЕ ПОЛНЫЙ КОД***

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать сенсоры для программы умного дома (задание)
Нужно сделать так что бы getValue выдавал либо off либо on и эта информация переходила в другой файл а точнее сервер